# What's so special about the "internal planets of Protostar Five"?

Tags: terry-pratchett, dark-side-of-the-sun

Charles Sub-Lunar posits that the existence (and discovery) of the "internal planets of Protostar Five" is proof-positive of the existence of infinite alternate universes and probability mathematics.

> "Probability math arises from the premise that we dwell in a truly infinite 
>   totality, space and time without limit, worlds without end—a creation so 
>   vast that what we are pleased to call our cause-and-effect datum Universe 
>   is a mere circle of candlelight. In such a totality we can only echo the 
>   words of Quixote: **All things are possible... vindicated with the predicted discovery of the Internal Planets of Protostar Five."**
>
> **Then humanity could be sure, even from this tiny grain of proof.** On either side were ranged the alternate Universes, uncounted millions differing perhaps by the orbit of an electron. Further, the difference must be greater still, until in the looming shadows on the edge of imagination came the universes that had never known time, stars, space or rationality.

**What's so special about these planets?**

Comment: I haven't read the book, but based on these quotes I think, in some multiverse, I will.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing *particularly* special about them, except that their existence (and discovery) were successfully predicted in advance by the use of Probability Math, thereby vindicating it.

To put that another way: the reasoning isn't "the Internal Planets exist, therefore there are infinite alternate Universes" but rather "the Internal Planets exist *as predicted*, therefore Probability Math works, therefore there are infinite alternate Universes."

(Note that this implies that there is no feasible way to find planets inside a protostar unless you already know where to look, since otherwise the "prediction" might have been fraudulent.  I'm a bit dubious about that from a real-world perspective, but it's not a blatantly absurd premise for soft science fiction.  I'm thinking that very few protostars have internal planets so even just finding the right star would be a needle in a haystack scenario.)